# Wave equation and taking partial derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was brushing up on my knowledge of wave propogation, and came across the 3d wave equation:

$$\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial z^2}=\frac1{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial t^2}$$

Now, say you were lucky enough to guess the forms:

$$A(x,y,z)=A_0\sin(k_{x}x)\sin(k_{y}y)\sin(k_{z}z)$$
and
$$A(t)=A_0\sin(wt).$$

Now I have read in a textbook that:

$$k_{x}^2+k_{y}^2+k_{z}^2=\frac1{c^2}w^2.$$

I attempted to derive this myself but wasn't able to do so:

I tried and got:

$$[k_{x}^2+k_{y}^2+k_{z}^2][-A_0\sin(k_xx)\sin(k_yy)\sin(k_zz)]=-w^2A_0\sin(wt).$$

How should I finish this relation?

Comment: Please format your equations.

Comment: It would be nice if you could format your question in a right manner, as this is not your first question.

Comment: Working on it now, sorry! @Dylan

Comment: There is a systematic method to derive the solution of the wave-equation (instead of just guessing), it's called [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables). We make the ansatz $A(x,y,z,t) = A(x)B(y)C(z)D(t)$. Inserted into the PDE it gives ODE's for $A,B,C$ and $D$. This method applied to this problem gives rise to a relation between constants like the one you are trying to derive. Another method one can use is [Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) which also (and perhaps more directly) gives the desired relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear what your $A(x,y,z)$ and $A(t)$ are. Presumably they are factors in the *ansatz* $A(x,y,z,t)=A(x,y,z)A(t)$. If so, substituting them into the wave equation yields an equation that differs from your last equation precisely by the factors that you're missing to cancel $A$ on both sides.

I don't know how you arrived at your last equation – it looks as if you substituted $A(x,y,z)$ on the left and $A(t)$ on the right – if so, that would be meaningless, since the equation is meant to be satisfied by a single function and any equation can trivially be satisfied by substituting different functions for different occurrences of the unknown function.

Comment: Very true, thanks for clarification. I had overlooked that my solutino was meaningless and trivial; I'll go back and study the separation of variables and the fourier solutions.